# Copy files using globbing (where no match), zsh

Tags: zsh, glob

In `zsh` on a command line I can get this to work as desired:

```
cp some_dir/!(0*).jpg dest_dir/
```

and it will copy over all files which do not begin with `0` to `dest_dir`.

But when I try to use the same from a `zsh` script, I get the following error:

```
no matches found: some_dir/!(0*).jpg
```

What's the problem here, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

This feature requires the shell option `KSH_GLOB` to be set:

```
setopt kshglob
```

See the [ZSH Manual on *ksh-like Glob Operators*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators) for more information.

---

Alternatively, one can set the option `EXTENDED_GLOB` and use `^` to negate (partial) patterns:

```
setopt extendedglob
cp some_dir/(^0*).jpg dest_dir/
```